# See which windows are open with quicklaunch on Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

I am using Lubuntu 18.04 with LXDE and I would like to have a feedback on which windows are already open. Currently the quicklaunch looks like this :

[Screenshot of the quicklaunch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ3TS.png)

Sure, I can use `Alt+Tab` to swhitch between windows but is there a way to highlight them on the quicklaunch?

Comment: Are you using LXQt on 18.04?  The left most icon is a LXDE logo usually found on the menu system as found in Lubuntu 18.04 LTS.  LXQt is also EOL on 18.04 being the last Lubuntu Next project (it wasn't a LTS release, the LTS release used LXDE)

Comment: I am using Lubuntu 18.04.1 for i686 and yes you are right sorry, I thought it was LXQT I am going to update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add "Task Bar (Window List)" to the panel.

[image]

Then your open windows are shown in the middle of the panel.

[image]

This is LXDE on top of stock Ubuntu so it looks a little different than yours but I think the answer still applies.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly, this is what I wanted!